# react-native is missing the /scripts folder in the node_modules/ and causing trouble for iOS builds

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

native, I started using EXPO to build with a

> create-react-native-app

It was fine until I decided to actually create a IPA file to upload to apple to have more testing done by other users, so I did an init and created the needed files for ios and android deployment.

I am getting errors from Xcode building my IPA file over telling me that there is no scripts folder inside react-native, like

> node_modules/react-native/scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh: cannot
>   execute: No such file or directory

and sure enough opening the folder for node_modules/react-native there is no scripts folder there. I'm not sure what the problem is, the react version I am using is 0.46.1.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. Did you get solution for this ?

Comment: I ditched npm and migrated to yarn, which seems to fix the problem, if you want a more dirty and easy method, you can grab node_modules folders that work like in local, and just upload it to the server, well, at least for my repository it worked.

Comment: How did you ditch npm?  Did you delete the node_module folder and run `yarn` or something?  Thanks!

Comment: yarn is a npm variant so you just install yarn, and replace npm with yarn on all console commands, like yarn install, yarn upgrade or yarn run whatever, you don't need to delete anything. And it will create a file like Gemfile.lock which will keep all library versions.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. I find the solution with using old version 0.44.0 ->  `react-native init --version="0.44.0" app`.

Comment: Yes it working with **0.44.0**. But why its not working with latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your current directory path and please remove your **'whitespace'** in any folder name.This is very important.

I solved the issue using the following links:

[Got the solution 1](https://medium.com/@jjerryhan/hi-bala-maruthavanan-as-you-can-see-the-error-log-that-error-was-from-white-space-on-your-782cb8279970)

[Got the solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252182/react-native-build-failed-due-to-double-conversion)

Answer (score -1):

Delete `third-party` folder from `node_modules/react-native/`

Comment: Doesn't work like this. You may have to change the script within Swift project in IOS xcode.